# Creating .NET runtime envoriment

Tags: .net

So I am trying to set up .NEt runtime envoriment on my machine, can someone tell me what are all the neccessary software that I need? I know I need to install Ms Visual Studio, what else do I need to set up the run time envoriment?

Comment: The VS installer will ensure you have the appropriate prerequisites.

Comment: Is this for software that is to be deployed on a customer machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, a runtime is the software necessary to run something written under a particular development framework or system. For example, a user needs the Java runtime installed in order to run software written in Java. Likewise, you need the .NET runtime installed in order to run software written using one of the .NET languages (C#, VB.NET, etc.).

If that's what you need, you do not need Visual Studio. If, however, what you need is a *development environment* (meaning the software necessary for you to *create* software), then you need Visual Studio. In that case, the Visual Studio installer will ensure that you have everything necessary to write .NET software. You will not need to install anything else manually unless you want to use third-party components.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to run a basic .NET Framework application is the .NET Framework.

- Windows Vista came with the .NET Framework 3.0.
- Windows 7 came with the .NET Framework 3.5.
- Windows 8 comes with the .NET Framework 4.5.

You can download the .NET Framework 4.5 (includes all previous .NET frameworks back to 2.0) here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

---

If you want to develop a simple .NET applicaiton, you will also need Visual Studio, but that's it, nothing more. Visual Studio includes all necessary .NET development components.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the .NET Framwork version you want to target, you need the appropriate Framework installer from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/net